Evaluation of Riemann Roch basis in Magma
I'm trying to evaluate the basis of a Riemann-Roch space of the divisor $G$ of the rational function field $F$ over $GF(2^{16})$ at 8 places of $F$ using Magma. When building the sequence of outputs, I get the error,

Runtime error in sequence construction: No valid universe containing all
elements

When I enumerate the evaluations of the elements of the basis over each place, I see that most of them are infinity, meaning that the basis functions have poles at those places. I grabbed the first 8 places of degree 1 in $F$. How do I find places & construct $G$ to avoid this happening?
EDIT: My function below
q := 2^16;
Fq := GF(q);
F<x> := FunctionField(Fq);
places := Places(F, 1);
G := &+[places[i] : i in [1..8]];
B := Basis(G);
pi_matrix := [];
for f in B do
    Append(~pi_matrix, [Evaluate(f, places[i]) : i in [1..8]]);
end for;

EDIT: Here are the contents of the basis B:
[
    ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^3)^-1
    * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1) * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^2 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^3 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^4 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^5 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^6 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1,
    ($.1)^7 * ($.1 + Fq.1^6)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^2)^-1 * ($.1 +
        Fq.1^3)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^4)^-1 * ($.1 + Fq.1^5)^-1
]


I have never used Magma, but I have used divisors and the related Riemann-Roch spaces. Can you shed a bit more light on what's going on? Apparently G is a divisor of the function field. What's the role of the variable k? To get a clue of what's going on, can you make it list the elements of B? Are B and basis_L_G the same thing or what?

My first suspicion is that the way you defined the divisor, you specifically allow poles up to order $1$ at places[1], of order $2$ at places[2] et cetera. In coding theory (the application I'm most familiar with) we typically allow poles only at the infinite place, forcing the functions in $L(G)$ to be polynomials, and only expect to be able to evaluate those functions at places disjoint from the support of $G$.

I edited the post with the elements of B. $.1 is the generator of F and Fq.1 is the generator of Fq.

The problem is probably occurring because, as @jyrki says the output list nessicarily has some infinity in it. Magma allows you to evaluate functions to infinity, but magma is quite strongly typed so it won't let you make a list with infinity and some other field elements in it

How do I get places and construct a divisor that won't evaluate to infinity on the basis?

If the infinite place is $#65537$, then you should get something nice by using the divisior $n P_{65537}$ for some small positive number $n$. The space $L(n\infty)$ is spanned by $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n$.

It might make sense to use $\Bbb{F}_4$ in the toy example. Simply to learn how these functions work! Anyway, $\Bbb{F}_q(x)$ has $q+1$ places of degree one, and I would guess the infinite place to be the last.

So I can't use divisors constructed with the finite places?

You should be able to. But evaluate them at points not included in the support of the divisor. At least my guess to the root cause of your problem is this. If your divisor allows poles at places numbered $1\ldots8$ then you could evaluate those functions at, say, places $9\ldots 16$. Evaluating them at the places where you specifically allow poles feels odd. Then again, I don't know exactly what you want to do here.
